# Should I include test runner module as a dependency in my module?

Tags: node.js, dependencies

My module has no dependency on its own but for running tests you need to install `jasmine-node` module. Should I include that module as a dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most package management systems have a special way of specifying dependencies that are needed only for the development. Python's `setuptools` has `extras_require`, Clojure's `leiningen` has profiles, and `npm` has `devDependencies`: [see docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html).

Answer (score 0):

devDependencies is exactly what you are looking for. However, if this is a package that you only occasionally need, you can use something else.

My npm package is `install-subset`, and can be installed globally with `npm install -g install-subset`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-subset

First, you build whitelists and blacklists for named install subsets in your package.json like this:

`"subsets": {
    "build": {
        "whitelist": [
            "babel-cli",
            "dotenv"
        ]
    },
    "test": {
        "blacklist": [
            "eslint",
            "lint-rules",
            "prettier"
        ]
    }
}`

Then call it with, for example, `install-subset test`

This will temporarily rewrite your package.json to not install those packages blacklisted, then restore it, which depending on the packages can save a lot of time and bandwidth.